# How to create multiple vertical lines jfreechart

Tags: jfreechart, series

I want to create verical lines , the thing is , for example i have a space between x=0 and x=20 , and i have a jtextfield where the user can digit a number , and that number will create the same number of vertical lines in that space of x=0 and x=20. i'm using xyplot , and the problem is , if i use the same series to add the points i will get a zigzag line , for exemple if i do:

```
       series.add(0,-2)
       series.add(0,2) 
       series.add(4,-2) 
       series.add(4,2)
```

So for differents coordenate xx i have to have a different seried . But if i do a different series i have to do a diferente dataset too, because when i try to add different series to the same dataset i get a error. i thought about using a for loop to create differents dataset and differents series , but i have no ideia how can i do that . i could use the grid line to do this , but i only want to see the lines between x=0 and x=20 , and i don't know if i can do that with the grid line , and i don't know how to change the space between grid lines . 
So maybe you can tell me so ideias about this , and if you could guide me , that would be great.

Comment: For reference, "series" is both a singular and a plural form; "serie" is not an English word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a facility in [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) to add "markers" to a plot to mark particular values along an axis.  The markers are typically drawn as lines across the plot, perpendicular to the x-axis (domain markers) or the y-axis (range markers).  In your case, it sounds like you want to add a fixed number of domain markers to the plot, so you should call the [addDomainMarker()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#addDomainMarker%28org.jfree.chart.plot.Marker%29) method on the plot.